# Set command puts all parameters into %1 %2 %3 etc

Tags: batch-file

A few years back I remember using a set command that would take a variable separated by spaces that would assign each value to `%1` `%2` `%3` etc

I read a line from a file which has the following structure

```
"log file"  "B:\Current\log" "B:\Backup\warehouse" "Warehouse_Day"
```

and assign it to a variable lets say `params`, then do the infamous `set` command `params`, and then automagically I could use each parameter independently.

If I did `echo %1`, I would get `log file`
if I did `echo %2`, I would get `B:\Current\log`
if I did `echo %3`, I would get `B:\Backup\warehouse`

Does anyone remember or know what the command was?

Comment: Do you mean `for` loops?

Answer (score 3):

When I understand you right, this is what you think of:

```
@echo off
set /p "params="<params.bat
echo %params%
call :program %params%
echo %1, %2, %3, %4 are gone.
echo --%param4%--
goto :eof

:program
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
echo %4
set param4=%4
```

Of course the `%n` parametes are only valid within the called subroutine and are gone, when you return from the subroutine (but you can derive other variables from them).

If you need to get rid of the quotes, use `%~1`, `%~2` and so on.